# search and replace multiple patterns in R

Tags: r, grepl

I'm attempting to use grepl in nested ifelse statements to simplify a column of data containing researchers' institutional affiliations with the country they belong to, i.e. '1234 University Way, University, Washington, United States' would become 'United States'. The column contains universities in over 100 countries. At first I tried nested ifelse statements with grepl:

H$FAF1 <- ifelse(grepl("Hungary", H$AF1), "Hungary",
                 ifelse(grepl("United States", H$AF1), "United States", ...

etc., but I realized the limit is 50 for nested ifelse statements. Does anyone know another way to do this? I tried writing a function but am unfortunately not that adept at R yet.

Comment: `H$AF1<-regmatches(H$AF1,regexpr(paste(countries,collapse = "|"),H$AF1))`

Comment: `countries<-c("Hungary","United States")`

Comment: Thanks @Onyambu. That received the following: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "AF1", value = c("Hungary", "Hungary",  : 
  replacement has 7694 rows, data has 7731

Comment: Since it’s in a df use str-extract from stringer pakage

Comment: Thanks. It ended up working, not all of the addresses included country name; I corrected the missing data and everything went smoothly.

Comment: Even had forgotten about this.great.. am happy for you

Answer (score 1):

An alternative for the regex-approach by csgroen, where you have to write down countries manually, you could try the `countrycode`-package, where they are already included, which might save you some time... Try:

```
countrycode::countrycode(sourcevar = "1234 University Way, University, Washington, United States", 
                         origin = "country.name", 
                         destination = "country.name")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using str_extract? I've made a little example.

```
min_ex <- c("1234 University Way, University, Washington, United States", 
            c("354 A Road, University B, City A, Romania"),
            c("447 B Street, National C University, City B, China"))

library(stringr)
str_extract(min_ex, regex("United States|Romania|China"))
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that there are over 7,000 entries, which makes copying and pasting addresses one-by-one impractical (re: min_ex).

Comment: Instead of min_ex, you'll pass the column containing addresses. I just made a little example for reproducibility's sake. For the regex, you should probably grab a list of country and paste them all together with `|` as a separator. But `regex` parsing is quite fast

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Thanks for the clarification, it works very well!

Comment: (with the exception that it deletes values that don't contain a phrase included in the vector (i.e. min_ex)).